# List of integers to a concatenated String in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm hoping someone can steer me in the right direction.  What I am trying to accomplish is

I have a growing list of integers lets say the list name is listOfIntegers.

I want to cycle through each element and return a string stringOfIntegers with the values for all the ints in the current list with a space in between them.
''
so for instance when I cycle thru listOfIntegers I get for example stringOfIntgers = "1 2 3 4 5 6" etc.

Does someone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<int> intList = [1,2,3,4,5];
var str = intList.join(" ");
```